# Send Tweet with Variable using tweepy

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter, tweepy

So I'm trying to send out a tweet with a variable using tweepy. To be exact, the whole tweet is a variable.

Code snippet:

```
tweet = '"If you don\'t think every day is a good day, just try missing one." - Cavett Robert\n\n Tweet URL: https://twitter.com/\nhttp://redd.it/31a5k0'
status = api.update_status(status=tweet)
```

When I run that, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#76>", line 1, in <module>
    api.update_status(status=tweet)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\tweepy\api.py", line 193, in update_status
    )(post_data=post_data, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\tweepy\binder.py", line 239, in _call
    return method.execute()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\tweepy\binder.py", line 223, in execute
    raise TweepError(error_msg, resp)
tweepy.error.TweepError: Twitter error response: status code = 403
```

It's not because the tweet is too long. It's 139 characters.

When I use `api.update_status(status='Hello')` it works completely fine. It's only when I use the variable it breaks.

I've also tried the following:
`api.update_status(status='%s' % tweet)`
`api.update_status(status=('%s' % tweet))`
`api.update_status(status='{0}'.format(tweet))`
`api.update_status(status=str(tweet))`

Now I'm new to python so I don't understand the error completely. Could someone please tell me why this isn't working and how I can correctly use it?

Comment: How are you authenticating to twitter? Are your API keys valid?

Comment: Yes @ThomWiggers. I did say it works fine when I don't use a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The long tweet with the two links is actually over 140 characters after Twitter wraps the links (https://dev.twitter.com/overview/t.co). Each link ends up being 22 characters.

Answer (score 2):

The error code you receive is the `HTTP 403: Forbidden` status code, so your API call is somehow forbidden by the Twitter API, not by `tweepy`.

According to the [Twitter API docs](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/post/statuses/update):

> Any attempt that would result in duplication will be blocked, resulting in a 403 error. Therefore, a user cannot submit the same status twice in a row.

Therefore, try changing your content, it might be working afterwards.

Comment: Not the problem. Changed it slightly and still got the same error.  
And if it means a duplicate of any existing tweets of mine, the profile I'm trying to tweet from has 0 tweets.

Comment: But still, a `403` means your script is trying to do something the Twitter API doesn't allow. Try to find something there!

Comment: I read through the page you linked and couldn't find any issues. Granted, I have no idea what to look for exactly.